# Returning an element with a specific rank k in a binary tree

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, rank

I already implemented a method `rankOfElement(x)` in pseudocode which returns the rank for a given node x:

```
function rankofElement(x) {
    rank = 0; 
    Node temp = root;

    while (temp.key != x) {
       if (x < temp.key) {
          temp = temp.leftson
       } else if (x > temp.key) {
          rank += temp.leftson.size + 1;
          temp = temp.rightson;
       } else if (temp.key == x) {
          return rank + temp.leftson.size
       } else return "key not found"
   }
```

Now I should implement a method (`elementbyRank(k)`) in pseudocode which returns a node with a specific rank k in the context of a binary tree. 
I am struggling with that and I hope you can give me an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, if given rank k and we need to find a node with the given rank we first need a traversal algorithm to search through the tree. A pre-order traversal should work just fine. Here is a recursive one.

```
function preOrderTraversal(node){
    if(node !== null){
        print(node.data);
        preOrderTraversal(node.left);
        preOrderTraversal(node.right);
    }
}
```

now that we have a way to get through our tree we need to implement the `elementbyRank` method and modify the traversal algorithm. Instead of printing the data we will check each node's rank. we will need to pass rank we need to find and we will need to add a return to the traversal.

The elementbyRank method is pretty simple:

```
function elementbyRank(k){
   return preOrderTraversal(root, k);    
}
```

Now we need to make the changes to the prePrderTraveral and let's change the name as well to elementbyRankTraversal.

```
function elementbyRankTraversal(node, key){
    if(node !== null){
        if(key == rankofElement(node.key))
            return node;    

        return elementbyRankTraversal(node.left);
        return elementbyRankTraversal(node.right);
    }
    return null;
}
```

So now if we find a node with the passed in rank, we will get that node back. but if one does not exist we will instead get a null value.

I know that you said given `node x`, the `rankofElement(x)` will return the rank of the element. but you are comparing the `node's key` directly to `x` which tell me that `x` is not a `node` but `x` is the `key of node x`. If I'm wrong then just remove the key part from `elementbyRankTraversal()`.

And that should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am pretty sure that your solution would work but I should have mentioned that the method should work in O(h) time where h is the height of the binary tree. In your solution the maximum time would be O(h^2).

Comment: Well, the hard part is out of the way no. I would suggest having each node store it's rank then using the traversal algorithm which is O(n) to find the desired rank. This would add a bit of complexity to your insert and delete methods, but it will get the job done.